# Investr package strange behaviour with dplyr mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working on a script for calibration curve comparison (analytical chemistry).

To simplify: I have independent variable exp_conc (concentration of calibration solutions used to calibrate)
and detector response. I build different models (linear, quadratic, and with different weighting).

In analytical chemistry, one of the methods to compare calibration curves is to compare residuals of independent value.
For the linear model inverse estimation is straightforward ((response-intercept)/coefficient).

But I need to do it for all models linear and quadratic, and in the later part of the script for automatically chosen model.

I tried to do it using Investr package.

And there is my problem (not my script - just a simplified example for linear regression; for quadratic it is the same):

Function inwers_est is to extract only estimation from investr object.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(investr)

inwers_est <- function(model, response) {
  a <- invest(object = model,
              y0 = response,
              upper = 450,
              lower = -20)
  
  a <- unname(unlist(a[1]))  
  return(a)
}

exp_conc <- c(1, 4, 15, 35, 70, 130, 220, 300, 400)

response <- c(0.002793995, 0.010526501,
              0.039554726, 0.094275798,
              0.199609618, 0.366600791,
              0.736514866, 0.918911425,
              1.275848925)

samp <- data.frame(exp_conc, response)

regnwl <- lm(response ~ exp_conc, data = samp)

samp <- samp %>%
  mutate(
    conc_1= (response-regnwl$coefficients["(Intercept)"]) /regnwl$coefficients["exp_conc"],
    conc_2 = inwers_est(regnwl, response))

for (ziutek in 1:nrow(samp)) {
  samp$conc_3[ziutek] <- inwers_est(regnwl, samp$response[ziutek])
}
```

Running this code I get:
[image]

But why?
Why conc_2 is different from conc_1 and conc_3?
InvestR calculates correct concentrations when doing it one by one in the for loop but in mutate it gets always the same value.

BR Radek

Comment: That is rather easy to solve I guess. Add  `rowwise() %>%` before `mutate()`.

Comment: Thank you.  It works. If you would be so kind to explain to me why `conc_1= (response-regnwl$coefficients["(Intercept)"]) /regnwl$coefficients["exp_conc"]` works without rowwise but my function not. I'm a bit confused.